# Centering a 100% dynamic image within a div

Tags: css

Having some problems centering a 100% image inside a div on a responsive site I am trying to build.

Tried margin:auto and text-align:center....

Are there any other options to center a image within a div, or even the div. where the actual width of the div isn't specified?

```
<div class="hoods"><a href="http://example.com.com/hoods"><img    src="http://example.com.com/image/data/Home Page  /hoods.jpg" ></a></div>

.hoods {
float: left;
margin-bottom: 20px;
width: 96%;
}

.hoods > a > img {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px;
max-height: 236px;
max-width: 92.5%;
}
```

Comment: If a divs width isn't specified it will be 100% of the parent unless floated or otherwise affected by CSS.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking....what are you trying to center, the div or the image in the div? - http://jsfiddle.net/z1spcw12/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Answer (score 2):

**Inline Centering**

When you have an image, which should be centered, then you can do it in two ways. Just for an inline image, with dynamic `width` and `height`. You can do the following:

```css
.center-image {text-align: center;}
.center-image img {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="center-image">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

**Dead Centre** (Absolutely Centering in the Whole Window)

If you wanna do a dead-center, then you can use `translate()`:

```css
.center-image {text-align: center; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
.center-image img {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="center-image">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: Will the inline-centering still work if the .center-image div is set at 100%?